# „Welcher“ zur Kennzeichnung explikativer Relativsätze?

Tags: relative-clause, relative-pronoun

Beim Meditieren über [diese Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6319/welcher-versus-der) ist mir eingefallen, dass ich *welcher* u. Ä. manchmal als Relativpronomen nutze, um zu betonen, dass der Relativsatz explikativ ist. Ein Beispiel:

> A) Derjenige Verdächtige, der vorbestraft ist, ist schuldig.
>   B) Der Verdächtige (der vorbestraft ist) ist schuldig.
>   C) Der Verdächtige, der vorbestraft ist, ist schuldig.
>   D) Der Verdächtige, welcher vorbestraft ist, ist schuldig.

A ist unmissverständlich: In einer Gruppe von Verdächtigen gibt es einen Schuldigen, der sich durch eine Vorstrafe abgrenzen lässt (restriktiver Relativsatz). B ist ebenfalls eindeutig: Der Verdächtige ist schuldig und ergänzend wird mitgeteilt, dass er vorbestraft ist (explikativer Relativsatz). Variante C ist mehrdeutig, wobei es vom Kontext abhängt, ob eine restriktive oder explikative Interpretation wahrscheinlicher ist.

Nun aber zur eigentlichen Frage: Wenn ich einen explikativen Relativsatz schreiben möchte, die Gefahr der Mehrdeutigkeit besteht und Option B aus irgendeinem Grund ausscheidet, würde ich Variante D nutzen, um die Explikativität zu betonen. Umgekehrt würde ich bei Variante D eher zu einer explikativen Lesart neigen als bei Variante C. Habe nur ich diese Tendenz oder zeichnet sich hier eine ansetzende Sprachentwicklung ab, die eventuell schon dokumentiert wurde?

Comment: Was bedeutet denn *explikativ* genau? Ich kann zwischen A, B, C, D keinen Unterschied feststellen.

Comment: explikativ meint hier, dass über eine bereits identifizierte Entität weitere Information bereitgestellt wird. Die Grenze ist fliessend und kann auch davon abhängen, was der Zuhörer weiß.

Comment: Oder, um eine andere Herangehensweise zu wählen: Wenn ein restriktiver Relativsatz weggelassen wird, funktioniert der Hauptsatz nicht mehr – bei einem explikativen ist dies nicht der Fall. Zwei eindeutige Beispiele: *Ich habe mal einen Menschen gesehen, der sechs Finger hatte.* enthält einen restriktiven Relativsatz. *Ich sehe meine leibliche Mutter, die rote Haare hat.* enthält einen explikatven Relativsatz. In Englischen werden explikative Relativsätze übrigens im Gegensatz zu restriktiven durch Kommata abgetrennt.

Comment: Aber wenn ich x Jahre im Wald lebe, dann herauskomme und der Nächste, den ich treffe, mich fragt, was ich so erlebt habe in der Zeit, kann ich sagen: "Naja, ich habe mal einen Menschen gesehen." Funktioniert also auch alleine. Ich verstehe zwar, worauf ihr hinaus wollt, aber ich sehe trotzdem keinen Unterschied zwischen den oben angegebenen Beispielsätzen.

Comment: Natürlich kann man bei fast jedem (geschriebenen) Beispiel einen Kontext finden, in dem der Relativsatz explikativ bzw. restriktiv ist. Aber dann hat der Satz eine andere Bedeutung und wird in der Regel auch anders betont. Explikative und restriktive Relativsätze sind also im Deutschen in der Regel [homograph](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homograph). In anderen Sprachen (z. B. Englisch, s. o.) ist dies jedoch nicht der Fall. Auch kann ich mit den Optionen A) und B) im Deutschen explizit kennzeichnen, was für eine Art Relativsatz vorliegt.

Comment: Stimme der Lesart von A als restriktiv und B als explikativ zu, sehe jedoch effektiv keinen Unterschied zwischen C und D. Mein Eindruck ist, dass die meisten Menschen nach Lust und Laune entscheiden, wann sie hier "der" und wann "welcher" verwenden. Häufig wird die Unterscheidung mit anderen Mitteln ausgedrückt, z.B. `Der Verdächtige, der/welcher **übrigens** vorbestraft ist, ist schuldig` (explikativ);  und für die restriktive Variante behilft man sich mit einer Umstellung: `Schuldig ist der Verdächtige, der/welcher vorbestraft ist.`

Comment: Zu B: Ich sehe diese Eindeutigkeit hier nicht, mir ist auch keine Konvention o.ä. bekannt, dass Klammern nur explikative Zusätze enthalten dürfen. Gesprochen ist die Eindeutigekeit ohnehin dahin.

Comment: @frafl: Rechtschreibregeln §86: »Mit Klammern schließt man Zusätze oder Nachträge ein.« Ein restriktiver Relativsatz ist wohl kaum Zusatz oder Nachtrag, da er ja zentral für den ursprünglichen Satz ist. Und dass etwas in Klammern o. Ä. steht, kann man sehr wohl sprechen.

Comment: Wie spricht man etwas in Klammern anders als den (gleich lautenden) Relativsatz, sodass jeder Klarmmern versteht? Die oben genannte Regel wird in der Praxis häufig verletzt. Vielleicht ist der Trend zu ganzen Sätzen (restriktiver Art) in Klammern verbreiteter als "welcher" zur Kennzeichnung von explikativen Nebensätzen.

Comment: @frafl: Die explikative Variante würde ich (im obigen Beispiel) mit einer kleinen Pause vor dem Relativsatz, sowie einem Sprechen des Relativsatzes mit leicht gesenkter Stimme und leicht erhöhter Geschwindigkeit betonen. Im expliziten Fall würde ich eine kleine Pause nach dem Relativsatz einlegen, sowie beide *der* betonen. Selbst wenn sich die Nutzung von Klammern dahingehend wandelt, dass der Inhalt der Klammern immer wichtiger wird (was ich bezweifle), wird sie wohl kaum so weit geraten sein, dass zentrale Nebensätze in Klammern getütet werden. Wer das tut, provoziert Missverständnisse.

Comment: Klammern sind leichter wahrzunehmen als Kommata und existieren paarweise, was ihren Einsatz für kurze Einschübe empfehlenswert macht. Lange Einschübe sind dagegen weder mit Klammern noch mit Kommata gut lesbar.

Comment: Klammern sind ein Element der Schriftsprache, insofern sie nicht der Darstellung einer Betonung, Intonation, etc., dienen. Insofern sind B und C gesprochen nicht zu unterscheiden. Intuitiv wird der Unterschied für mich faktisch nur durch die Intonation geregelt.

Answer (score 5):

Da *welcher* als Relativpronomen grundsätzlich weniger verwendet wird als *der/die/das* und als Interrogativpronomen weniger klar bzw. abgrenzend wirkt als *der/die/das* als bestimmte Artikel, somit *welcher* also "schwächer" wirken könnte als *der/die/das*, scheint mir eine Tendenz zu explikativer (vorsichtigerer) Interpretation durchaus begründbar, die mit der "Abnutzung" der Sprache und damit dem Seltener-werden von *welcher* durchaus zunehmen könnte.

Dem liesse sich entgegen halten, dass *welcher* als Fragewort im Gegensatz zu den bestimmten Artikeln implizit eine grössere Menge Dinge als vorhanden angibt, aus der ausgewählt wird und die gefühlsmässig auch beim Relativpronomen angenommen werden könnte, so dass für *welcher* einzig eine ehre restriktive Interpretation in Frage kommt. (Wenn Überhaupt irgendeine Beziehung zwischen den beiden Bedeutungen von *welcher* existiert.)

Grundsätzlich sind *welcher* und *der* als Relativpronomen jedoch genau gleichbedeutend (nach meinem Sprachgefühl jedefalls).

Answer (score 0):

Sämtliche obigen Beispiele sind eher ungewöhnlich und weisen eine Wiederholung auf ("ist"). Viele würden die beiden Sachverhalte wohl so ausdrücken (also gar keine Nebensätze verwenden):

- Restriktiv: "Schuldig ist der vorbestrafte Verdächtige." Dieser Satzbau impliziert fast immer, dass **nur er** schuldig ist.
- Explikativ: "Der vorbestrafte Verdächtige ist schuldig."

Comment: Die Beispiele sind halt eben solche und dienen vor allem der Darstellung des Sachverhalts und sollen kein Beispiel für elegante Sprache sein. Es gibt diverse Fälle, in denen eine derartige Umstellung des Satzes eben nicht möglich ist. Nebenbei kann »Der vorbestrafte Verdächtige ist schuldig.« auch restriktiv sein (in gesprochener Sprache auf jeden Fall bei Betonung von *vorbestrafte).*

Comment: Da stimme ich zu. Es kommt bei der zweiten Form immer auf den Kontext und die Betonung an. Bezüglich der Beispiele: Auch wenn die nur konstruiert sind, sehe ich das so wie Eugene Seidel oben. Zwischen C und D gibt es keinen Unterschied, der auf restriktiv/explikativ schließen ließe.

Comment: In beiden Beispielen kann zwischen restriktiv und explikativ gewechselt werden durch die Intonation. Gleichwohl wirkt es etwas affikiert. Genau genommen bin ich mir nicht sicher, wie man dein erster Beispiel genau intonieren soll. Liegt eine Betonung auf 'vorbestraft'?

Answer (score 0):

Der explikative/restriktive Chararakter hängt vor allem von der Information ab:

Vergleiche

> Das Boot, das vorher extra am Bootssteg befestigt wurde, riss sich los.
>
> Das Boot, welches vorher extra am Bootssteg befestigt wurde, riss sich los.

mit

> Gesucht wird der Halter des Wagens, der das Kennzeichen XY 0000 trägt.
>
> Gesucht wird der Halter des Wagens, welcher das Kennzeichen XY 0000 trägt.

Niemand kann erwarten, mit einer Information, die auf etliche Boote zutrifft, ein Boot zu indentifizieren. Ein Kennzeichen sollte aber genau diese Funktion haben.

Im Beispiel mit dem Angeklagten hängt es vom Wissen der Kommunikationspartner ab, ob der Einschub als restriktiv wahrgenommen wird.

Comment: Beim zweiten Beispiel denke ich spontan, dass man einen *"Halter mit Kennzeichen"* und nicht einen Wagen sucht.

Comment: Das habe ich mir auch schon gedacht, aber so eine missverständliche Durchsage wäre eher Regel als Ausnahme.

Comment: Dass der Bedarf an einer Unterscheidung zwischen restriktiven und explikativen Relativsätzen kontextabhängig ist, ist mir bewusst.

Comment: Mag sein, aber wenn ein Trend, wie er in der Frage skizziert wird, existiert, dann müsste er auch in Fällen funktionieren, die vom Kontext dominiert sind. D.h. welcher bzw. der müsste in je einem der Fälle ausgeschlossen sein.

Comment: @frafl: Ja. (D.h.: Ich würde dazu _tendieren,_ im ersten Beispiel *welches* und im zweiten Beispiel *der* zu nutzen. Aber eben auch nur tendieren, insbesondere da hier keine Mehrdeutigkeit droht.)

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Da sollten Textart (welcher eher in Literatur) und persönliche Präferenzen eine größere Rolle spielen als explikativ/reskriktiv.