# Eingeschobener Nebensatz bei Modal-Ausdruck mit "gern" - Kommasetzung

Tags: punctuation

Eine Grundtendenz im Deutschen für Kommasetzung ist diese:

> Pro finitem Verb ein Komma (bei eingeschobenen Nebensätzen zwei).

Klar, es gibt Ausnahmen, aber man kommt ganz gut damit durch. Bei folgendem Satz bin ich mir jedoch nicht sicher. Der Nebensatz ist ein vollwertiger Nebensatz und würde in anderen Kontexten sowohl initial als auch im Nachfeld als auch eingeschoben durch Komma getrennt.

> Nachdem es geregnet hat, gehe ich spazieren.
>
> Ich gehe spazieren, nachdem es geregnet hat.
>
> Ich gehe, nachdem es geregnet hat, spazieren.

Aber was ist hiermit?

> Ich gehe nachdem es geregnet hat gerne spazieren.

Ein Teil von mir sähe gern zwischen *hat* und *spazieren* ein Komma, aber dazu müsste vor *nachdem* auch eins sein und das kommt mir komisch vor. Also …
Komma oder nicht?
Wie ist die Regel?

EDIT:

Nach der Antwort von @Vogel612 habe ich nach einem besseren Beispiel gesucht.

> Ich lese gerne, bis ich müde bin.

Die Aktivität, die ich gerne mache, ist hier für mich *lesen* und *dunkel werden* ist eine Ausnahme.

> Ich lese gerne bis es dunkel wird.

Hier ist die Aktivität *SOLANGE lesen, bis es dunkel wird*. Vielleicht lese ich gar nicht gerne einfach mal so.
Die Kommata bringen also einen Bedeutungsunterschied mit sich … und das gleiche Gefühl habe ich auch bei meinem Originalbeispiel.

Kann das jemand nachvollziehen?

Gibt es da eine Regel dazu?

Ist beides richtig (mit und ohne Komma)?

Comment: Was ist der Unterschied zwischen dem dritten Beispiel im Mittelblock und deinem Problemsatz, abgesehen von dem Wort "gerne"? Du musst auf jeden Fall zwei Kommas in den Satz setzen, die Regel dürfte die selbe sein, wie im Beispielsatz davor. Etwas komplexer ist es, wenn die Verben nicht direkt aufeinander folgen: "Ich gehe nachdem es geregnet hat gerne spazieren" Da müsste ich auch erstmal in Ruhe nachdenken, ob es nicht überflüssig geworden ist. Aber Nebensätze mit *nachdem* werden immer mit Komma abgetrennt. Willst du ohne Komma auskommen: "Ich gehe gerne nach dem Regen spazieren"

Comment: Ich hab' die Frage geändert und deine Satzstruktur genommen. Ich weiß nicht wieso, aber zwei Kommata in den Satz zu setzen scheint mir eine Cäsur zur Folge zu haben, die absolut nix mit dem Inhalt zu tun hätte. Wenn ich es laut vorlesen müsste, würde ich mit Komma falsch betonen (sowohl in meiner als auch in deiner Version). Andererseits ist es ein nachdem-Satz und da ist normalerweise wie du ja sagts immer ein Komma... langer Rede kurzer Sinn... jetzt musst du mal in Ruhe nachdenken ;)

Comment: Interessant wäre auch, wie es wäre, stünde das *gerne* vorne (*"Ich gehen gerne..."*). Man könnte nämlich dann das Komma durch ein *und* tauschen.

Comment: @Takkat ich denke, das würde den Sinn des Satzes in diesem Fall doch stark ändern. Entweder: `Ich gehe nur gerne spazieren wenn es geregnet hat` oder: `Ich gehe gerne spazieren, sogar wenn es geregnet hat`

Comment: Das macht es um einiges klarer. Wenn du aber einen Bedeutungsunterschied unterstellst (ich empfinde das nebenbei genauso), dann kann man sogar annehmen, dass beide Varianten (also mit und ohne Kommata) korrekt sind. Damit stellt sich die Frage nach einer Regel gar nicht und die Antwort auf deine Frage lautet: Ja, es gibt einen Bedeutungsunterschied

Comment: Hmmmm... Im neuen Beispiel, ja, gehts ohne Komma. "Ich habe bis in den Tag hineingeschlafen" zb wird definitiv ohne Komma verwendet. Aber *nachdem* kann imho ausschließlich als Konjunktion verwendet werden und das verlangt ein Komma, da ein eingeschobener Satz Kommas verlangt.

Comment: Mein Argument für das Komma ist übrigens, dass der Einschub ein Prädikat enthält. Und bedenke ich dies, muss in deinem anderen Beispiel mit dem Dunkelwerden auch ein Komma, jedoch nicht in "Ich lese gerne bis zum Dunkelwerden". Deine Nebensätze sind aber im Grunde vollwertige Aussagen "Es wird dunkel" und "Es hat geregnet" enthalten Prädikate und werden durch eine Konjunktion als Nebensatz eingepflanzt. Daher benötigst du ein Komma um diese abzutrennen. Klingt das logisch?

Comment: ich verstehe es nicht!!! könnt ihr mir vlt. mit einem guten beispiel erklähren was ein eiingeschobener nebensatz ist???es würde mich freuen,danke!

Comment: @sandra: Ein eingeschobener Nebensatz ist einer, der seinen übergeordneten Satz irgendwo in der Mitte unterbricht. "Ich esse Nudeln, weil ich Hunger habe." - "Weil ich Hunger habe, esse ich Nudeln." - "Ich esse, weil ich Hunger habe, Nudeln."... das dritte ist ein solcher Satz

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Zunächst einmal § 74 der [Rechtschreibregeln](http://rechtschreibrat.ids-mannheim.de/download/regeln2006.pdf):

> Nebensätze grenzt man mit Komma ab; sind sie eingeschoben, so schließt man sie mit paarigem Komma ein.

Da alle in Frage kommenden Strukturen ein finites Verb enthalten, sind sie eindeutig Nebensätze und fallen unter diese Regel. Es gibt eine Handvoll Ausnahmen, die hier aber nicht zutreffen:

> Wie bereits gesagt gehe ich gerne spazieren. (Formelhafte Nebensätze; § 76)
>
> Auch(,) nachdem es geregnet hat, gehe ich gerne spazieren. (Mehrfach eingeleiteter Nebensatz; § 74, E1)
>
> Ich spaziere gerne und nachdem es geregnet hat. Ich gehe gerne und nachdem es geregnet hat, spazieren. (Nebensätze nach Konjunktionen; § 74, E2)

Von formelhaften Nebensätzen abgesehen gilt also, dass zwischen zwei finiten Verben immer ein Komma oder eine »beiordnende Konjunktion« (z. B. *und, oder, bzw.* – siehe § 72) steht.

---

Die Mehrdeutigkeit ist vergleichbar mit derjenigen zwischen explikativen und restriktiven Relativsätzen (ich klaue mal [meine eigenen Beispiele](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6321/welcher-zur-kennzeichnung-explikativer-relativsatze)):

> A) Derjenige Verdächtige, der vorbestraft ist, ist schuldig.
>   B) Der Verdächtige (der vorbestraft ist) ist schuldig.
>   C) Der Verdächtige, der vorbestraft ist, ist schuldig.
>   A2) The suspect who was previously convicted is guilty.
>   B2) The suspect, who was previously convicted, is guilty.

A (explikativ) und B (restriktiv) sind eindeutig, aber C kann sowohl wie A als auch wie B gelesen werden. Im Englischen entscheidet die Explikativität eines Relativsatzes gerade über die Kommasetzung und A kann nur mit A2 übersetzt werden und B mit B2. Aber nur dass andere Sprachen hier die Mehrdeutigkeit vermeiden können, ändert nichts an der Mehrdeutigkeit von Beispiel C im Deutschen – und auch nicht an seinen Kommata. Nur dass Mehrdeutigkeiten möglich sind, weicht die Regeln der Kommasetzung nicht auf.

Comment: " Ich gehe gerne und nachdem es geregnet hat, spazieren.".. das sieht für mich soooo falsch aus :). Aber logisch ist es schon.