# Kommasetzung bei "war dass"

Tags: comma

> Was mir nicht gefallen hat, war dass er sich entschuldigt hat.
>
> Was mir nicht gefallen hat war, dass er sich entschuldigt hat.

Which one, if any of them, is correct?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Keines von beiden, es müssen beide Kommata gesetzt werden:

> Was mir nicht gefallen hat, war, dass er sich entschuldigt hat.

*War* steht hier alleinig im Hauptsatz; alles andere sind Nebensätze, denn sie enthalten konjugierte Verben. Dies wird hoffentlich ersichtlich, wenn man je einen der beiden Nebensätze durch etwas anderes ersetzt:

> Das Schlimmste war, dass er sich entschuldigt hat.
>   Was mir nicht gefallen hat, war seine Entschuldigung.

Generell gilt, dass zwischen zwei konjugierten Verben immer ein Komma oder eine beiordnende Konjunktion *(und, oder, …)* stehen muss (einzige Ausnahme sind formelhafte Nebensätze, die aber hier nicht vorliegen; siehe auch [diese Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/7514/2594)).

Answer (score 7):

You need both commas:

> Was mir nicht gefallen hat, war, dass er sich entschuldigt hat.

*"Was mir nicht gefallen hat"* is a subordinate clause taking the place of the  subject, *"war"* is the predicate and *"dass er sich entschuldigt hat"* is another subordinate clause acting as a complement.

It becomes clear if you insert "die Tatsache" as the complement:

> Was mir nicht gefallen hat, war die Tatsache, dass er sich entschuldigt hat.